# Number occurrences in another cell (Excell)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the example below there's a columnA with names and a columnB counting how many instances that the name occurs. How can I write a formula for ColumnB that I can paste so I don't have to manually count the number of occurrences of each name.

Note: The names are sorted so they are grouped together and the count stars back at one when there's a new name.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Assuming your first name starts at A1 you would put this formula in B1 .... `=COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1)`. Then drop down formula as needed.

Comment: @urdearboy wow that was so much simpler than I expected. Thank you!